# What happens in CouchDB when I create an index repeatedly?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-nano, couchdb-fauxton

To implement sorting, in CouchDB we have to create an index (otherwise the corresponding mango query fails). I haven't found a way to do this in Fauxton (if I have missed something, please comment in [Github](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/issues/1384)), so I've decided to create it programmatically. As I'm using couchdb-nano, I've added:

```
this.clientAuthPromise.then(async () => {
    try {
        await this.client.use('test_polling_storage').createIndex({
            index: {
                fields: [
                    'isoDate',
                ],
            },
            name: 'test_polling_storage--time_index',
        })
        console.log('index created?')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`failed to create index:`, error)
    }
})
```

into the storage class constructor, where

```
this.clientAuthPromise = this.client.auth(connectionParams.auth.user, connectionParams.auth.password)
```

Now, on each run of the server, I'm getting `index created?`, so the [`createIndex` method](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#dbcreateindexindexdef-callback) (which presumably [POSTs to `/db/_index`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-index)) doesn't fail (and sorting works, too). But as I haven't found indexes viewer in Fauxton either, I wonder what actually happens on each call of `createIndex`: does it create a new index? Does it rebuild the index? Or sees that the index with such name already exists and doesn't do anything? It's annoying to deal with this in a blind fashion, so please clarify or suggest a way to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as the [docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#db-index) suggest that the response will contain "created" or "exists", I've tried

```
const result = await this.client.use('test_polling_storage').createIndex({
...
console.log('index created?', result.result)
```

got `index created? exists` and concluded that if the index was created before, it won't be re-created. It's not clear what will happen if I try to change the index, but at least now I have a mean to find out.